# mod_wsgi cannot load my Flask app

Tags: python, apache, flask, mod-wsgi

I am trying to run my Flask application with mod_wsgi, but mod_wsgi gives the error `Target WSGI script '/var/www/FDApp/fdapp.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.`

```
mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/3.5.1+.
mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/3.5.2.
mod_wsgi (pid=4142): Target WSGI script '/var/www/FDApp/fdapp.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
mod_wsgi (pid=4142): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/FDApp/fdapp.wsgi'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/FDApp/fdapp.wsgi", line 6, in <module>
    from main import app as application
  File "/var/www/FDApp/main.py", line 15, in <module>
    import label_faces
  File "/var/www/FDApp/label_faces.py", line 2, in <module>
    import mxnet as mx
ImportError: No module named 'mxnet'
```

The mxnet package is installed in python3.5. All the packages are installed in this folder.

```
        <VirtualHost *:80>
                        ServerName 127.0.0.1
                        WSGIDaemonProcess fdapp user=www-data group=www-data threads=5  python-path=/home/teja/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages
                        WSGIScriptAlias /fdapp /var/www/FDApp/fdapp.wsgi process-group=fdapp application-group=%{GLOBAL}
                        <Directory /var/www/FDApp/>
                                WSGIProcessGroup fdapp
                                WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
                                WSGIScriptReloading On
                                Order allow,deny
                                Allow from all
                        </Directory>

                        Alias /static1 /var/www/FDApp/static
                        <Directory /var/www/FDApp/static/>
                                Order allow,deny
                                Allow from all
                        </Directory>
                        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                        LogLevel warn
                        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        </VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /fdapp /var/www/FDApp/fdapp.wsgi
```

to:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /fdapp /var/www/FDApp/fdapp.wsgi \
    process-group=fdapp application-group=%{GLOBAL}
```

You aren't telling mod_wsgi to run your application in the daemon process group.

Also, using:

```
python-home=/home/teja/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages
```

is wrong.

For per user `site-packages` use:

```
python-path=/home/teja/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages
```

Comment: I have change **python-home** to **python-path**.....and changed that **WSGIScriptAlias** tooo...But same error.Do i need to change any other?

Comment: The other problem is that the directory ``/home/teja`` is likely not accessible to the user that Apache runs as. You are better of creating a Python virtual environment under ``/var/www/FDap`` and install packages into that. Then use ``python-home`` to refer to the root of the Python virtual environment. See http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html